# smartgwt listgrid RestDataSource not populating

Tags: spring, datasource, smartgwt, listgrid

Im new using this front end framework application...

I recently started to work with smartgwt and i'm bulding a new application with a Spring MVC integration.

I'm using a ListGrid with a RestDataSource (Consume the Rest service with **mvc:annotation-driven** for plain JSON)

I can see that the servaice gets consuming properly perhaps my grid is never shown with the data in it.

Can someone help me here ?

Here's my ***ListGrid*** class

public class ListGrid extends com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid {

```
private final SpringJSONDataSource springJSONDataSource;

public ListGrid(List<DataSourceField> fields) {
    this(new PatientDataSource(fields));
}

public ListGrid(SpringJSONDataSource springJSONDataSource) {
    this.springJSONDataSource = springJSONDataSource;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setAutoFetchData(true);
    setAlternateRecordStyles(true);
    setEmptyCellValue("???");
    setDataPageSize(50);

    setDataSource(springJSONDataSource);
}
```

}

***Now there's the DataSource implmentation***

public abstract class SpringJSONDataSource extends RestDataSource {

```
protected final HTTPMethod httpMethod;

public SpringJSONDataSource(List<DataSourceField> fields) {
    this(fields, HTTPMethod.POST);
}

public SpringJSONDataSource(List<DataSourceField> fields, HTTPMethod httpMethod) {
    this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);
    addDataSourceFields(fields);
    setOperationBindings(getFetch());
    addURLs();
}

private void addURLs() {
    if(getUpdateDataURL() != null)
        setUpdateDataURL(getUpdateDataURL());

    if(getRemoveDataURL() != null)
        setRemoveDataURL(getRemoveDataURL());

    if(getAddDataURL() != null)
        setAddDataURL(getAddDataURL());

    if(getFetchDataURL() != null)
        setFetchDataURL(getFetchDataURL());

}

private void addDataSourceFields(List<DataSourceField> fields) {
    for (DataSourceField dataSourceField : fields) {
        addField(dataSourceField);
    }
}

protected abstract OperationBinding getFetch();
protected abstract OperationBinding getRemove();
protected abstract OperationBinding getAdd();
protected abstract OperationBinding getUpdate();

public abstract String getUpdateDataURL();
public abstract String getRemoveDataURL();
public abstract String getAddDataURL();
public abstract String getFetchDataURL();
```

}

***The class PatientDataSource that extends SpringJSONDataSource***

public class PatientDataSource extends SpringJSONDataSource {

```
public PatientDataSource(List<DataSourceField> fields) {
    super(fields);
    setPrettyPrintJSON(true);
}

@Override
protected OperationBinding getFetch() {
    OperationBinding fetch = new OperationBinding();
    fetch.setOperationType(DSOperationType.FETCH);
    fetch.setDataProtocol(DSProtocol.POSTMESSAGE);
    DSRequest fetchProps = new DSRequest();
    fetchProps.setHttpMethod(httpMethod.toString());
    fetch.setRequestProperties(fetchProps);

    return fetch;
}

@Override
public String getFetchDataURL() {

    return "/spring/fetchPatients";
}

@Override
protected OperationBinding getRemove() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getRemoveDataURL() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected OperationBinding getAdd() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAddDataURL() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected OperationBinding getUpdate() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getUpdateDataURL() {
    return null;
}
```

}

***My spring controller PatientControler***

@Controller
public class PatienController {

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PatienController.class);

@Autowired
private PatientServices patientServices;

@RequestMapping(value = "/patientTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object getTest()
{
    return patientServices.getAllPatients();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchPatients", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object getAllPatients()
{
    return patientServices.getAllPatients();
}
```

}

***PatientServiceImpl***

public class PatientServicesImpl implements PatientServices {

```
public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {

    List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    Patient patient;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 500 ; i++){
        patient = new Patient();
        patient.setDateOfBirth(new Date());
        patient.setFirstName("Joe");
        patient.setMiddleName("Moe");
        patient.setLastName("Blow");
        patient.setLastConsultation(new Date());
        patient.setSex(Sex.M);

        patients.add(patient);
    }

    return patients;
}
```

}

***Im Really stuck right now i've been looking for all type of answers .... but so far nothing worked when i tried to override the transformResponse from my RestDataSource impentation the parameter "data" as an OBJECT, returns me an array [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data which is transferred from the RestDataSource has a specific format which is described in the [JavaDoc of the RestDataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html)
Your server must understand the request and send back a valid response.

At the moment your example doesn't seem to honour the contract.

To debug the traffic send to and from your server you can use the SmartClient-Console. You can open it by a browser bookmark like this:

```
javascript:isc.showConsole()
```

Of cause you need to deploy this console by adding the following module to your `gwt.xml`

```
<inherits name="com.smartclient.tools.SmartClientTools"/>
```

Now go to the *RPC* Tab and check *Track-RPCs*

Comment: Thx! For the hint for the debug. I've found my answer this morning before reading your post. And yes like you said... since i'm not using the smartgwt server side... i have to accomodate with the standards of the format returning by the json

{    
     response:{
        status:0,
        startRow:0,
        endRow:76,
        totalRows:546,
        data:[
            {field1:"value", field2:"value"},
            {field1:"value", field2:"value"},
            ... 76 total records ...
        ]
     }
  }